# I need the event params of two diffent events that triggered during the same session for GA4 on BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

1. The following query extract the events params for the event `purchase` that I need:

   ```
   SELECT
      event_date,
      event_name,
      traffic_source.medium,
      traffic_source.source,
      (
      SELECT
        value.string_value
      FROM
        UNNEST (event_params)
      WHERE
        KEY= 'form_id') AS form_id,
      (
      SELECT
        value.int_value
      FROM
        UNNEST(event_params)
      WHERE
        KEY = 'ga_session_id') AS session_id,
    FROM
      `table1`
    WHERE
      event_name = 'purchase'
   ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfcun.png)

2. This other query unnest the events params of a custom event that i need to join with the registers of the `purchase` event above:

   ```
   SELECT
      event_date,
      event_name,
      (
      SELECT
        value.int_value
      FROM
        UNNEST(event_params)
      WHERE
        KEY = 'ga_session_id') AS session_id,
      (
      SELECT
        value.string_value
      FROM
        UNNEST(event_params)
      WHERE
        KEY = 'campaign_id') AS experiment_id,
      (
      SELECT
        value.string_value
      FROM
        UNNEST(event_params)
      WHERE
        KEY = 'campaing_name') AS experiment_name,
      (
      SELECT
        value.string_value
      FROM
        UNNEST(event_params)
      WHERE
        KEY = 'variation_name') AS variantion_name 
        #COUNT(1) AS sessions
    FROM
      `table1`
    WHERE
      event_name ="kameleoon_experiment"
   ```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtaU8.png)

3. We have on both querys the common value of the event.key `ga_session_id`

What would be the query to join in the same row the event params of purchase and the event params of the custom event for the same `ga_session_id?

I am currently downloading the results of the querys separately and then vlookup both tables using `ga_session_id` as key.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of a relationship is between those two events.
If there is no (not solid) dependency and you want just to show them in one row, then you can use full join.

This should look like:

```
WITH
  purchase AS (
  SELECT
    event_date,
    event_name,
    traffic_source.medium,
    traffic_source.source,
    (
    SELECT
      value.string_value
    FROM
      UNNEST (event_params)
    WHERE
      KEY= 'form_id') AS form_id,
    (
    SELECT
      value.int_value
    FROM
      UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE
      KEY = 'ga_session_id') AS session_id,
  FROM
    `analytics_.events_*` gae --
  WHERE
    gae.event_name = "purchase"
)
,kameleoon_experiment AS (
  SELECT
    event_date,
    event_name,
    (
    SELECT
      value.int_value
    FROM
      UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE
      KEY = 'ga_session_id') AS session_id,
    (
    SELECT
      value.string_value
    FROM
      UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE
      KEY = 'campaign_id') AS experiment_id,
    (
    SELECT
      value.string_value
    FROM
      UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE
      KEY = 'campaing_name') AS experiment_name,
    (
    SELECT
      value.string_value
    FROM
      UNNEST(event_params)
    WHERE
      KEY = 'variation_name') AS variantion_name
  FROM
    `analytics_.events_*` gae --
  WHERE
    gae.event_name = "kameleoon_experiment"
)
-- Join two tables in one row
SELECT
  pur.event_date,
  pur.event_name,
  pur.medium,
  pur.source,
  pur.form_id,
  pur.session_id,
  --kam.event_date,
  --kam.event_name,
  --kam.session_id,
  kam.experiment_id,
  kam.experiment_name,
  kam.variantion_name
FROM
  purchase pur
FULL JOIN
  kameleoon_experiment kam
ON pur.event_date = kam.event_date
  AND pur.session_id = kam.session_id ;
```

But usually, there is some relationship between those two (like purchase is always triggered and kameleoon_experiment only based on certain conditions after).
In such a case, you should use "LEFT JOIN" or "INNER JOIN" instead.

You can check some posts about this i.e.: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-join-set-1-inner-left-right-and-full-joins/